# WCF 3.5 and UDP

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, wcf-binding

Is it possible to make udp binding in wcf 3.5 or it's only possible in .net 4.0 ?

If it's possible in .net 3.5 could somebody give me an example please ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to implement your own Binding, you can try walking through this Blog Tutorial on creating a Custom UDP Binding for WCF:

[Waleed Mohamed: How to Implement UDP as a custom WCF Transport](http://waleedmohamed.net/?s=How+to+Implement+UDP+as+a+custom+WCF+Transport&submit=Search)

Comment: Thanks, Justin, so that meen it's not default supported by .net 3.5, that's rigth ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not available as out of the box binding but some implementation of UDP transport is offered in official [transport extensibility samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967733(v=VS.90).aspx). This custom transport can be then used in custom binding.